# Jar with compiled class files in different directories with Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a java project with multiple source directories. I use the build-helper-maven-plugin to compile them. Layout as follows:

```
project
      |
      |-src-
      |    |-com/example1-
      |                  |-Test.java
      |
      |-src2   
      |    |-META-INF
      |             |-classes
      |             |       |-com/example2
      |             |                    |-Test2.java
      |             |
      |             |-Manifest.mf 
      |
      |-MavenDependencies
```

For reasons I care not to explain right now, I need to produce a jar file looking something like this.

```
jar-
   |-com/example1-
   |            |-Test.java
   |
   |-META-INF
            |-classes
            |       |-com/example2
            |                    |-Test2.java
            |
            |-Manifest.mf
            |
            |-lib
```

I know there must some plugin that can be used to achieve this, just can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the "Maven Assembly Plugin": http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Since it seems you are building a non-standard jar, the assembly plugin will allow you to put whichever files you want wherever you want them to go.

Comment: I ran across that plugin before, but wasn't sure it would work. Looking at it again, did some more research and managed to assemble the jar file I needed. Thanks!